# Diferencias entre fechas - semanas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, table

Hola bello stackoverflow, es mi primera vez preguntando algo y espero puedan ayudarme con mi pequeña duda.

Tengo una duda con referente a la semana del año con MySQL, actualmente me encuentro trabajando en una base de datos de una escuela la cual lleva un control de pagos y ellos manejan pagos por semana, en la imagen se muestra como funciona lo de las semanas.

[image: Problema actual]


En la tabla que lleva el registro de pagos se llama db_pagosalumnogrupo lo único que guarda de fechas es cuando se hace algún pago.

[image: Tabla pagos Alumnos]

Se ocupa una segunda tabla para saber cuando se inscribió el alumno los pagos semanales que tiene que hacer, el costo de inscripción, a partir de cuando se le empezara a cobrar la ultima semana en que pago y el ultimo año en que pago (todo esto varia dependiendo al grupo al que pertenezca)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta que ahora me surge es como podria obtener este resultado en MySQL usando las 2 tablas que menciono, ya intente varias opciones pero sigo sin poder llegar al resulto que deseo obtener que es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me ayudarían de mucho saber la respuesta....
Estas son las 2 tablas que utilizo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Leí tu pregunta y me parece que le falta detalle a la explicación, por eso te sugiero leer [ask]. No olvides indicar claramente el resultado que esperas, en el contexto en el que lo esperas. No olvides que para resolver algo, antes de cualquier lenguaje, debes entender como hacerlo _a mano_.

Comment: Quizás no has hecho ese ejercicio y por eso tu explicación es poco clara. Si ya lo has hecho y no sabes como lograrlo, incluye una explicación detallada de como lograr lo que esperas, además de lo que has intentado y las dificultades que tienes con ello.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando como referencia la última semana y contando el número de pagos (semanas) hacia atrás.
Tienes que particionar por grupo ordenando por fecha;
difícil de hacer sin MySQL v8.

```
SELECT pag.fecha
     , pag.pagos
     , ag.lastweek -sum(pag.pagos) over w +1         SI
     , ag.lastweek -sum(pag.pagos) over w +pag.pagos SF
  FROM db_alumnosgrupo ag
    INNER JOIN db_pagosalumnogrupo pag
      ON    pag.alumno = ag.student
        AND pag.grupo = ag.idgroup
    WINDOW w as ( partition by ag.idgroup order by pag.fecha desc )
  ORDER BY pag.fecha
```